# How do I combine two private Worksheet_Change subs into one in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have this code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rngList As Range

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngList = Range("AB3").CurrentRegion

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B18:B19")) Is Nothing Then  ' user is in column-A
        Target.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, rngList, 2, False)
    End If

    Set rngList = Nothing
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rngList As Range

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rngList = Range("AC3").CurrentRegion

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B10:B11")) Is Nothing Then  ' user is in column-A
    Target.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, rngList, 2, False)
End If

Set rngList = Nothing
```

End Sub

I would like to combine them so that I can use both, but I don't know how to do so without conflict, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your question is not very clear - what do you mean by "so that I can use both"? You want that both run on a change event? You want to be able to choose any of them on a change event? In that case how do you choose one or the other?

Comment: Basically, I have dropdowns that target a range, then shift it to the right (Category Name - Category Value), I have about 8 different dropdowns, and the code above only works on one. It works by clicking a cell, which initiates a dropdown, and then when the value in the cell is selected, the code shifts the value one to the right to the corresponding value. 


Sorry if this is ambiguous, I am still trying to grasp VBA in general

Comment: `Target` is the cell that triggered the change. So you can test if `Target = Range("XXX")` and act accordingly, with a `Select Case` statement for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this should do the trick you were trying to do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    WorksheetChanged Target, Range("AC3").CurrentRegion, Range("B10:B11")
    WorksheetChanged Target, Range("AB3").CurrentRegion, Range("B18:B19")

End Sub

Private Sub WorksheetChanged( ByVal Target As Range, ByVal rngList As Range, ByVal intersectRng As Range )

    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Target, intersectRng) Is Nothing Then  ' user is in column-A
        Target.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, rngList, 2, False)
    End If

    Set rngList = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here you have a private function which gets the Ranges as Parameters. You can call this function as often as you want (though Excel might become a bit slow if you call it too much in the Worksheed_Change Sub).

Comment: Thank you, that is along the right track! The only thing is that the first sub gives me an error on the two WorkSheetChanged() functions (is that the right name?), it throws an error which reads : Compile Error : Expected =

I had a look but nothing too out of the ordinary, any ideas? Thank you

Comment: It seems as though is requires something after WorksheetChanged() in the form of =, that's all I can discern

Comment: Maybe we should change the function to a sub, which does not return anything.

Comment: And if this is the answer to your question, please vote and mark as accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Have seen that in your other question ;)